# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, access-violation

I'm getting this error while trying to pass array of string from C# to C++. This error appears sometimes, not always.

Declaration in C#

```
[DllImport(READER_DLL, 
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern void InstalledRooms(string[] rooms,int length);
```

In C++

```
void InstalledRooms(wchar_t const* const* values, int length);

void DetectorImpl::InstalledRooms(wchar_t const* const* values, int length)
{
    LogScope scope(log_, Log::Level::Full, _T("DetectorImpl::InstalledRooms"),this);
    std::vector<std::wstring> vStr(values, values + length);
    m_installedRooms=vStr;
 }
```

How it is invoked from c#?

```
//List<string> installedRooms = new List<string>();
//installedRooms.add("r1");
//installedRooms.add("r1"); etc
NativeDetectorEntryPoint.InstalledRooms(installedRooms.ToArray(),installedRooms.Count);
```

Error is raised at

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at MH_DetectorWrapper.NativeDetectorEntryPoint.InstalledRooms(String[] rooms, Int32 length)
```

Any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: It could be that your P/Invoke declaration should be using a StringBuilder (but this is a complete guess!): public static extern void InstalledRooms(StringBuilder[] rooms,int length);

Comment: Try adding [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] string[] rooms

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm not sure you're correct, also according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713288/c-passing-array-of-strings-to-a-c-dll

Comment: You will need to write code to catch this exception then dump the contents of `rooms` and `length` to determine the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but since the error is intermittent I believe this is a memory issue related to the `string` array `installedRooms`.

If you do not mark a managed object using `Fixed` keyword, `GC` may change the location of the object at any time. Thus, when you try to access to the related memory location from unmanaged code, it may throw error.

You may try the following;

```
List<string> installedRooms = new List<string>();
installedRooms.add("r1");
installedRooms.add("r2"); 
string[] roomsArray = installedRooms.ToArray();

fixed (char* p = roomsArray)
{
    NativeDetectorEntryPoint.InstalledRooms(p, roomsArray.Count);
}
```

Comment: I tried to simulate the problem using two threads  1. Thread one to send array from c# to c++ in a loop.  2. Second thread for garbage collection. But this never reproduced bug. Is there a better way to reproduce the bug and then test the solution with certainty. @daryal

Comment: I could not use your solution, I get compile time error for 'fixed (char* p = roomsArray)'. Error is:Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('string'). As per [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559384/cannot-take-the-address-of-get-the-size-of-or-declare-a-pointer-to-a-managed-t array of string can't be fixed type